# How to query all records from multiple tables with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my main table `employee_rates_year`:

```
tier   skill   rate   year
1      28      110    2019
2      28      101    2019
```

my column `skill` is connected to an employees table and subcontractors table, for simplicity here is a shortened version of `tblEmployees`:

```
EMPLOYEEID   Skill   FullName
1            28      Employee One
2            28      Employee Two
```

and `tblSubcontractors`:

```
SUBCONTRACTORID   Skill   FullName
1                 28      Sub One
2                 28      Sub Two
```

I am trying to get a tier, rate and year show up for every individual employee & subcontractor.

I've tried using different joins but nothing seems to give me information with every employee/subcontractor.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee_rates_year
left join tblsubcontractors on employee_rates_year.skill = tblsubcontractors.skill
left join tblemployees      on employee_rates_year.skill = tblemployees.skill
```

The problem is that my query shows results like this:

```
tier    skill    rate    year    tblEmployees.FullName    tblSubcontractors.Fullname

1       28       110     2019    Employee One             Sub One
2       28       101     2019    Employee Two             Sub Two
```

Whereas I am trying to get:

```
tier   skill   rate   year   tblEmployees.FullName   tblSubcontractors.FullName

1      28      110    2019   Employee One
1      28      110    2019                           Sub One
2      28      101    2019   Employee Two
2      28      101    2019                           Sub Two
```

I have also tried using `WHERE` to try and differentiate between the two tables and pick individual records.

Comment: And how do you know the `tier`?

Comment: `tier` is a key referencing a subgroup of customers. That part of my query is functioning properly but is irrelevant to this I believe. It is not a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should never use `SELECT *`, because....

Try:

```
SELECT 
  tier,   
  skill,   
  rate,   
  year, 
  tblEmployees.FullName  As Employee
  '' As Subcontractor
FROM employee_rates_year
left join tblsubcontractors on employee_rates_year.skill = tblsubcontractors.skill
union all
SELECT 
  tier,   
  skill,   
  rate,   
  year, 
  '' As Employee
  tblSubcontractors.Fullname As Subcontractor
FROM employee_rates_year
left join tblemployees      on employee_rates_year.skill = tblemployees.skill
```

Comment: you should always qualify all column references .. 

Comment: I removed both columns with `' '`and this worked perfectly for me, thanks.

Comment: Oops, I am missing some ',' in my query.... If you want Employee and Subcontractor in different colums, than you should add a comma to the query above (after `tblEmployees.FullName  As Employee` and after `'' As Employee`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need `UNION ALL` and not a double join:

```
SELECT e.*, t.FullName EmployeesFullName, NULL SubcontractorsFullName
FROM employee_rates_year e
left join tblsubcontractors t on e.skill = t.skill
UNION ALL
SELECT e.*, NULL, t.FullName
FROM employee_rates_year e
left join tblemployees t on e.skill = t.skill
ORDER BY e.tier, e.skill
```

Each query of the 2 uses a join of `employee_rates_year` with 1 of the other tables. 
Finally the 2 resultsets are merged with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `union all` to bring the employees and subcontactors together and then `join` and `group by`.  To get values in "vertical lists", you can use `row_number()`:

```
select er.skill, er.rate, er.year,
       max(e_fullname) as e_fullname,
       max(s_fullname) as s_fullname
from ((select e.skill, e.fullname as e_fullname, null as s_fullname,
             row_number() over (partition by e.skill order by e.fullname) as seqnum
       from tblemployees e
      ) union all
      (select s.skill, null as e_fullname, s.fullname as s_fullname,
             row_number() over (partition by s.skill order by s.fullname) as seqnum
       from tblsubcontractors s
      )
     ) es left join
     employee_rates er
     on es.skill = er.skill
group by er.skill, er.rate, er.year, seqnum;
```

If you just want the values in separate lists (with `NULL`s), then you don't need the `row_number()` trick:

```
select er.skill, er.rate, er.year, e_fullname, s_fullname
from ((select e.skill, e.fullname as e_fullname, null as s_fullname
       from tblemployees e
      ) union all
      (select s.skill, null as e_fullname, s.fullname as s_fullname
       from tblsubcontractors s
      )
     ) es left join
     employee_rates er
     on es.skill = er.skill;
```

Comment: In the first `over` I am getting a syntax error for missing closing parenthesis. I have never worked with partitions before so I'm not familiar with the logic

Answer (score 0):

Think the problem (or part of the problem) is because of the "left join", which creates one row in result for each row in the "left" table.  Since employee_rates_year only has two rows, your result for query will only have 2 rows.